# why I am getting error when i try to retrieve a specific user by id

Tags: spring, rest

I can retrieve all data if i use localhost:/users  however, if i want to retrieve a specific user I get error:
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Feb 08 20:29:30 GMT-06:00 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).

the question is how can I retrieve a single user by not using "Predicate"

Thanks

```
@RestController

public class ControllerFirst {

    @Autowired
    private DataAccessObjectService service;
    
    
    


    

    
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<UserInfo> retriveAll() {
       return service.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public UserInfo retrieveUser(@PathVariable int id){
        return service.findOne(id);
    }
    
    

    @DeleteMapping(value="/users/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
         service.deleteById(id);
    }






@Component


public class DataAccessObjectService {


    
    private static List<UserInfo> users=new ArrayList<>();
    
    private static int counter=0;
    
    static {
        users.add(new UserInfo(1,"JAY", "CITY","STATE", "IL", 5555, 84578));
        users.add(new UserInfo(2,"jonny", "CITY","STATE", "IL", 11111, 9999));
        users.add(new UserInfo(3,"pual", "CITY","STATE", "IL", 3333, 5555));
    }
    
    public List<UserInfo>findAll() {
        return users;
        
    }
    public UserInfo save(UserInfo user) {
        user.setId(++counter);
        users.add(user);
        return user;
        
    }
    
    public UserInfo findOne(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Predicate<? super UserInfo> predicate = user -> user.equals(id);
        return users.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst().orElse(null);
        
    }
    
    
  public UserInfo deleteById(int id) {
        Iterator<UserInfo> iterator = users.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            UserInfo user = iterator.next();
            if (user.getId() == id) {
                iterator.remove();
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I think I did the necessary change but it still says error 400  This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Feb 09 18:20:15 GMT-06:00 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to compare Object `UserInfo` with primitive type int by calling `Object.equals(Object obj)` which is causing exception because primitive type int doesn't extend Object class.
Try and modify your predicate expression as follows

```java
... predicate = user -> user.getId() == id;
```

Comment: I did the necessary change but it  still the same does this console error mean anything?
.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; For input string: "id"]

Comment: How do you call your controller? From the message above it looks like you pass the String "id" as a path variable rather than an int value. Should be `localhost/users/2`